# How to define bbox value in TileCache tool?

Tags: geoserver, wms, tilecache

I have created a WMS layer on GeoServer and i would like to tile it using [TileCache tool](http://tilecache.org/), now. There are some definitions about bbox parameter in the web page of the tool but i can't understand.

In GeoServer, there is bbox like depicted below; (btw: projection is 3857)

[image]

And the configuration of TileCache is;

```
[LayerName]
type=WMS
url=http://address:8080/geoserver/wms?layers=LayerName&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&tiled=false
extension=png
srs=EPSG:3857
size=256,256
levels=22
bbox= ?
maxResolution= ?
extent_type=loose
```

I don't know how can i define bbox and maxResolution values. There is one more problem; tiling bbox value! If i would like to run command below, what should be the bbox value again?

```
> tilecache_seed.py LayerName 1 3 -b "(?) 3873263.280,4494756.762,4119659.272,4809662.117" -p 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just learned bbox values from [Open Source Geospatial Foundation Wiki Page](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WMS_Tiling_Client_Recommendation). According to documentation, Mercator Profile values should be like showed below;

```
Width: 256 px
Height: 256 px
Format: image/png
SRS: EPSG:3857
BoundingBox: -20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34
Resolutions: 156543.03390625 78271.516953125 ...
```

As you can see, the Bounding Box value for Marcator (3857) projection is,

**"-20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34"**

The second question was "tiling bbox value". Tiling bbox values are GeoServer Bounds values that is showed in image above or bounds of frame where you want to tile.